# (No errors btw) Why isnt my purge command working?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, purge

```py
@bot.command()
async def purge(ctx, limit=100, member: discord.Member=None):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  msg = []
  for m in ctx.channel.history():
    if m.author == member:
      msg.append(m)
  await ctx.channel.delete_messages(msg)
```

heres my code, this is a purge command with discord.py. Im trying to make it so it purges the message of someone you mention. Any help?

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to use the `channel.purge` method

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By Stack Exchange policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because `ctx.channel.history()` is an async function, so you'll have to use the `async` keyword before the loop. Like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def purge(ctx, limit=100, member: discord.Member=None):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  msg = []
  async for m in ctx.channel.history():
    if m.author == member:
      msg.append(m)
  await ctx.channel.delete_messages(msg)
```

You can also just use the `purge` function with a lambda instead. If you were to go that route, your code would look like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def purge(ctx, limit=100, member: discord.Member=None):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100, check=lambda msg: msg.author == member)
  await ctx.channel.send('Deleted {} message(s)'.format(len(deleted)))
```